# Left Join in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have the following models:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    patient_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    patient_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    patient_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    patient_email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class PatientMedicalRecord(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient)
    mrn = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    patient_height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    patient_weight = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    age_risk = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to query on patient table for getting all the patient. also i need MRN column value from PatientMedicalRecord table which contain record for particular patient if exists.
How can i do this with djnago ORM?

Following are sql query gives me perfect result.

SELECT a.id,--remaining field, b.mrn FROM patient as a LEFT JOIN patient_medical_record as b ON a.id=b.patient_id;

How can i do this with django annotate ?

Comment: is this a typo `patient = models.ForeignKey(PatientTable)` ? because inside your model you have Patient not PatientTable.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch related objects using the `object_set`. In your example, here is how you would do it:

```
patient = Patient.objects.get(pk=1)   # You can use any attribute to get the Patient object
patient_medical_records = patient.patientmedicalrecord_set.all()

patient_mrns = []
for record in patient_medical_records:
    patient_mrns.append(record.mrn)
```

You can also defined a `related_name` property in your model for the relationship to query relationships with. For example:

```
class PatientMedicalRecord(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='patient_records')
```

Then you would query it like this:

```
patient = Patient.objects.get(pk=1)
patient_medical_records = patient.patient_records.all()
```

Comment: instead of forloop you can use `patient.patientmedicalrecord_set.all().values_list('mrn',flat=True)`

Comment: It is definitely better. I did it with the forloop so it is easier for OP to understand.